# Forecasting Quarterly Sales with Daily Website Traffic (Mixed Frequency Problem)

Tags: time-series, forecasting, midas

I'm interested in using website traffic across multiple URLs to predict a particular company's quarterly sales. Thus this is the mixed frequency data problem because I'm using daily time series(s) to predict a quarterly time series. I only have 3 years worth of daily website traffic which would only be 12 data points for the quarterly sales data. I've been reading a lot about MIDAS regressions (suggested [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/218306/forecasting-with-mixed-frequency-data)), do I have enough data to use this algorithm? I can't find anywhere on the minimum length of history required?

These are some additional approaches that I've read:

1. Interpolate the quarterly data into a daily frequency (suggested [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/forecasting-kpis-ai-alt-data-erez-katz/)) then predict using an ensemble. This seems like the most straight forward.
2. State space methods such as Kalman Filters. Seems much more complicated than the others.

Please let me know your thoughts on tackling this problem.